# Acces Games on Linux Partition on Windows

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, games, steam

i installed Windows on an HDD and Linux (which i mainly use) is on an SSD. I installed some games on the SSD which are also on the HDD (namely Grand Theft Auto V, both on Steam). Since its not natively supported on Linux i basically have the same Version of the Game, one on an SSD, one on an HDD. Of course i want to play on the SDD, but Proton is slower for me since i have really low specs.

On Windows i cant acces the Linux Partition to play it on the SSD so im stuck with playing it on a HDD even though its installed on a SSD.

Any way to access that on Windows?

If not is there any way to play it on Linux without a Performance loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not a great way of achieving this without a loss of performance and/or features on one of the OSes:

- If you put the files in native Linux on a ext2/ext3/ext4 partition, you can use [Ext2Fsd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/) which, given that it hasn't been updated since 2017, doesn't bode well.
- If you put the files in native Windows on a NTFS partition, there's a read-only in kernel driver (which is performant) and the FUSE-based ntfs-3g driver (which is not so performant).  Paragon has their [in-kernel read/write NTFS driver](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-linux-free/) but it's not mainlined yet and looks to require registration.
- You can put the files in an exFAT partition which can be used by Windows and, as of kernel 5.4, used by an in-kernel driver in Linux.  The downside is that exFAT doesn't have a lot of the features that you might expect from a filesystem.